# como obtener datos de un json del back end al front end?

Tags: json, express

Estoy intentando obtener datos de un json (que simula una base de datos) en mi backend pero no sé cómo se hace para enviar el json desde el backend a el front end, aunque creo haber creado bien la request desde el front end, no sé cómo devolver el json. Aquí mi usuarios.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsuariosService {

  private userslist: any 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsuarios() {
    return this.http.get<[{nombre: string, contrasenia: any}]>('http://localhost:3000/login')
    .subscribe((usersData) => {
      this.userslist = usersData
    });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Respuesta corta: Tenes que invocar al metodo send del objeto "res":

```
app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send([
        {
            "usuario": "nico",
            "contrasenia": "nico"
        },
        {
            "usuario": "juan",
            "contrasenia": "juan"
        },
        {
            "usuario": "pedro",
            "contrasenia": "pedro"
        }
    ]);
});
```

Por otro lado, si es para testing, podes simplemente colocar el json como hice arriba.
Si lo tuvieras que tomar desde un archivo (aclaro que aca debes incluir el modulo "fs" **const fs = require('fs');** , y tampoco estoy controlando excepciones) podes hacer lo siguente:

```
   app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {

    fs.readFile( "/ruta/a/tu/archivo.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        res.send(data); 
    });
});
```

Editaste la pregunta y ahora no se entiende mucho, pero me base en lo que habias publicado de express.

Aclaro que en tu request estabas usando el metodo get, asi que en el back uso:

**app.get**('/login',...

Te dejo el ejemplo entero del back:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send([
        {
            "usuario": "nico",
            "contrasenia": "nico"
        },
        {
            "usuario": "juan",
            "contrasenia": "juan"
        },
        {
            "usuario": "pedro",
            "contrasenia": "pedro"
        }
    ]);
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`escuchando en el puerto ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Hola Karl, no se por que la pregunta no queda con el formato de codigo en las partes que quiero. Aún así, tu respuesta me sirvio mucho! ahora no se bien la sintaxis para recibir y usar el json desde el front, pero estoy meta tutoriales jaja te agradezco mucho tu respuesta amigo!

Comment: De una che. Suerte!